# ActionResult<object> Returns Status code 200, ActionResult.Result.Value does contain correct object, but ActionResult.Value is Null

Tags: .net-core, actionresult, http-status-code-200

I have a web api method that takes a object, saves the object to the db and then returns the updated db object using return new OkObjectResult(MyObject)... this works perfectly (Object appears in db, PK set and returned).

```
    public async Task<ActionResult<MyObject>> AddMyObject(MyObject, CancellationToken ct)
    {
       try
       {
           ......Add to DB, update PK in MyObject etc....
           return new OkObjectResult(MyObject);
       }
       catch (Exception ex)
       {
           ......
           return new BadRequestObjectResult("Unknown error adding MyObject to database");
       }
    }
```

However, when I call this method the ReturnedActionResultMyObject.Value is null

```
ActionResult<MyObject> ReturnedActionResultMyObject  = await AddMyObject(MyObject, ct);
ActionResult ReturnedResult = ReturnedActionResultMyObject.Result;
MyObject ReturnedValue = ReturnedActionResultMyObject.Value;
```

The ReturnedResult.StatusCode is 200 and ReturnedResult.Value has the correct MyObject, Visible when debugging.

I'm sure this should work and I should be able to get the returned MyObject.

Comment: might be a bit offtopic but since you are building a webapi, shouldnt u just be returning json? Also could you add a bit more context on where and how you are using the `AddMyObject` function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to cast your ReturnedValue to MyObjectType as

```
MyObject ReturnedValue = (MyObject)((Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ObjectResult)ReturnedResult).Value;
```

as

```
ActionResult<MyObject> ReturnedActionResultMyObject = await AddMyObject(MyObject, ct);                 
ActionResult ReturnedResult = ReturnedActionResultMyObject.Result;                   
MyObject ReturnedValue = (MyObject)((Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ObjectResult)ReturnedResult).Value;
```